# Best way to prevent a class from being Instantiated?

Tags: c#

I need to know how to prevent a class from being Instantiated in .net?

I know few methods like making the class Abstract and Static.

Is there any more way to achieve this?

Comment: "Not allowing to be instantiated" is the exact definition of `static class`. Why do you need something else?

Answer (score 24):

Making the class static is the best approach, if you *absolutely* don't want any instances. This stops *anyone* from creating instances. The class will be both sealed *and* abstract, and won't have *any* constructors.

Additionally, the language will notice that it's a static class and stop you from using it in various places which *imply* instances, e.g. type arguments and variables. This indicates the intention more clearly than just having a private constructor - which could mean that there are instances, created within that class (e.g. for a singleton implementation).

Oh, and making the class static will stop you from introducing any pointless instance members in the class, too :)

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) for more information about static classes.

Comment: Curious thing about static classes, they don't [look like classes at all](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2009/09/c-static-classes-are-not-real-classes.html); they're more akin to modules...

Answer (score 20):

Mark the constructor(s) `private`, `protected` or if in used from another assembly, `internal`

Comment: It can still be instantiated using reflection. And if it's not a sealed, you can just derive from it, and then use the protected constructor that you now have access to.

Answer (score 8):

Marking the constructor `private`. Of course, this doesn't prevent the class from instantiating itself through a `static` method, for example...

More practically, what's the purpose of disallowing class instantiation. If it's to have a *singleton*, then a `private` constructor is appropriate. If it's to force subclassing, making the class `abstract` is better; if it's to have a class with utility methods, making it `static` is one way (then you can only have `static` methods).

Comment: @RomeshSomani It depends on where you are trying to create the instance from. It you need to deny it entirely, make it abstract. edit - Sorry, I meant static.

Comment: No, abstract has a different purpose. Make it static.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to know how to prevent a class from being Instantiated in .net?

Your question is not clear.

Do you mean instantiated at runtime? Make the class `abstract` or `static`.

Do you mean that the constructor is not accessible in code? Make the constructor `private`. But note that someone could still use reflection to grab a handle on a constructor and instantiate an instance at runtime.

So, which do you mean?

Comment: I tried to use Activator.CreateInstance with a private constructor and it raised an exception

Comment: @AdrianIftode Check to see if your bindings are pulling private members.

Comment: @asawyer, I forgot about that ( I used Activator.CreateInstance<>)

Comment: Error: **an abstract class cannot be sealed or static**. Did you mean "`sealed`, `abstract` or `static`"?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is:

> How can you make your class not be instanced without having your class
>   be `static` or `abstract`?

Then the answer to this is to implement the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which in .NET 4+ this is done easily with:

```
public sealed class myClass
{
    private static readonly Lazy<myClass> lazyInstance = 
        new Lazy<myClass>(() => new myClass());

    public static Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyInstance.Value;
        }
    }

    private myClass()
    {
        // constructor logic here
    }
}
```

The singleton pattern allows you to pass your class around as a reference to methods, while still ensuring that you have only a single instance of your class. It also makes testing much easier as you can have a `ImyClass` instance which `myClass` implements, this is very helpful when making mock objects.

Without .NET4 you can still implement the singleton pattern, for example:

```
private static readonly myClass instance = new myClass();

public static Instance
{
    get
    {
        return instance;
    }
}

// rest of code remains the same
```

Which doesn't have deferred loading until it's called, there's lots of other ways as well (I think about 6 different ways), but the above two are the most common ones.

In summary the question is likely asking if you know the singleton pattern and if you recognise it's importance over static classes for unit tests and mock objects.

As others have already pointed out, `static` fields, even those marked `readonly` can be set with reflection, in addition the `private` constructor can be called using reflection. If you need to prevent these, either you need to make the calling code run in a less trusted app-domain space, or you will need to implement your class as `static`.

Generally though, people don't bother with such levels of reflection to get around your constraints unless they 'really need to' for example, writing obscure / extreme fringe case unit tests.